# Option to select provisioning profile for Mac Catalyst is grayed out

Tags: maui, mac-catalyst

I'm working on to create an app for Mac Catalyst platform using .NET MAUI. I'm already done with the creation of distribution certificate and provisioning profile. Also I have installed both. Now the problem is that I am unable to select the provisioning profile/certificate under Bundle Signing cause the option is grayed out.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a **certificate** for *Mac Development* or *Distribution* on *Apple Developer Portal* and download it in your **keychain access**. I recommend this document: [Provision an iOS app for app store distribution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macos/deployment/overview?view=net-maui-7.0) and although it's for iOS, the workflow for Mac app is similar.

Hope it works for you.

[image]

Comment: I'm aware of this process and already done it. I have created certificate and provisioning profile for Development and Distribution both but the problem is that I am unable to select it under Bundle Signing for Mac Catalyst. The dropdown to select certificate is grayed out.

Comment: First you could check if the Mac certificate is in the keychain. reopen vs and create a new project to see if it works.

Comment: Yes, I can see the certificate I created in Keychain and also I tried to create a new project but I am facing the same issue in the new project.

Comment: it's really weird. I use Visual Studio for Mac 17.4.1 and at least I could choose the Identity in Bundle Signing section. Besides, instead of Mac signing, does it work well in iOS Signing?

Comment: Yes, it's working fine for iOS Signing

Comment: Can you please check and confirm if you're able to select Bundle Signing Identity for Mac Catalyst?

Comment: Take a look at my answer. Did you mean this?

Comment: Yes, I am able to select Identity for iOS but not for Mac Catalyst. But can you please check and confirm if you're facing the same issue.

Comment: I can select identity for mac as the image in my answer is what i have tried

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood. Thanks for clarifying. It seems the problem is with my visual studio.

Comment: Thanks for your response! If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks Liqun. After I updated my Visual Studio, it is working fine. Now I am able to select identity for Mac. I have accepted your answer.